# Does this sequence of functions converge uniformly on $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: real-analysis

If $f_n:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $f_n \rightarrow 0$ uniformly on each closed and bounded interval $[a,b]$, does $f_n \rightarrow 0$ uniformly on $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Consider $f_n(x)=0$ for $\lvert x\rvert\le n$ and $1$ otherwise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, as a counterexample consider $$f_n(x) = \mathbb{1}_{(n,\infty)}(x)$$